# How can I tie multiple grids / tables / DACs to one header

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom screen which has a header and detail, which works fine.  I have a request to add several more detail sections / tabs to the screen, tied to the same header section - ala the Opportunities or Contacts screens.

My understanding, and the way I've always done it, is that when you set up the DACs between the header and detail, there is a [PXParent] attribute and a [PXLineNbr] used in the details DAC.  there is then a 'LastLineNbr' field used in the header, keeping track of the line number in the detail section, that is referenced in that detail PXLineNbr attribute as shown:

```
[PXLineNbr(typeof(HeaderTable.lastLineNbr))]
```

If that LineNbr field in the detail is tied to the LastLineNbr field in the header - how can you link more than one grid / detail table to that same header table as it's done in Opportunities or Contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field in the header table is referred to as the line counter by convention and is abbreviated Cntr. It's purpose is to provide a unique value for the key field of the detail entity.

A common misconception is that this field value needs to be sequential but since it's a technical field that is only required to be unique it's contract doesn't include providing sequential values.

That's the reason why SOLine DAC also adds a SortOrder field to provide sequential values:
[image]

> If that LineNbr field in the detail is tied to the LastLineNbr field
>   in the header - how can you link more than one grid / detail table to
>   that same header table as it's done in Opportunities or Contacts?

The constraint is that LineNbr be unique in the detail table, not that it be sequential. You could have multiple detail tables bounded to the same line counter. I believe that should work as it will always provide unique number. However since all detail table share the same counter the detail entity won't all start at 1. You could create 2 detail DAC1 with counter value 1 and 2. Then when you create detail DAC2 the counter will be at 3 instead of 1.

Reusing the same counter for different detail entity is not common though. Typically you would create one counter per detail entity in the master DAC.

SOOrder/SOLine and SOOrder/SOPackageInfo demonstrates that:

```
// Master DAC - SOOrder contains multiple Cntr fields used by multiple detail entity
class SOOrder : IBqlTable
{
    #region LineCntr for SOLine entity
    public abstract class lineCntr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<lineCntr> { }
    protected Int32? _LineCntr;
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXDefault(0)]
    public virtual Int32? LineCntr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LineCntr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LineCntr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region PackageLineCntr for SOPackageInfo entity
    public abstract class packageLineCntr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<packageLineCntr> { }
    protected Int32? _PackageLineCntr;
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXDefault(0)]
    public virtual Int32? PackageLineCntr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._PackageLineCntr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._PackageLineCntr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

// Detail 1 - SOLine uses SOOrder.lineCntr
class SOLine : IBqlTable
{
    #region LineNbr
    public abstract class lineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<lineNbr> { }
    protected Int32? _LineNbr;
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXLineNbr(typeof(SOOrder.lineCntr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Line Nbr.", Visible = false)]
    public virtual Int32? LineNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LineNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LineNbr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

// Detail 2 - SOPackageInfo uses SOOrder.packageLineCntr
class SOPackageInfo : IBqlTable
{
    #region LineNbr
    public abstract class lineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<lineNbr> { }
    protected Int32? _LineNbr;
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXLineNbr(typeof(SOOrder.packageLineCntr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Line Nbr.", Visible = false)]
    public virtual Int32? LineNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LineNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LineNbr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks much for your answer!  I'll give that a try.  ;D